# Delete models and collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Using Backbone.js:

When a user logs out is it normal to delete a bunch of models and collections?

That's what I plan to do in my application to prevent zombie data/bindings but I dont know if it's the best way to handle things.

If this is a good practice should I just call `delete this` on cleanup?

Comment: All assets are loaded on connect and we only use websockets after that initial load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the zombies you need to worry about come from binding to events. i wrote a post about this from the perspective of views: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

in your case with models, you should do the unbinding first and then delete the models and collections you don't need. calling `delete whatever` is the best way to ensure that things are truly gone. be sure to unbind from your model and collection events first, or you'll end up with bindings that point to undefined and cause exceptions.

Comment: You're always super helpful when it comes to this stuff, thanks! There  aren't a ton of good resources out there for what apps like this should really look like and it's great people like you are willing to help and give advice! Blog post is great.

Comment: :) thank you! always happy to hear that my thoughts are helpful!